# Why is apostrophe (') sorted before other ASCII characters?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, collation

Database: Azure Dedicated SQL Pool

Collation: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

```
create table testtable (timeenter nvarchar(30))

insert into testtable values('08:19:21''')
insert into testtable values('08:19:21$')
insert into testtable values('08:19:21%')
insert into testtable values('08:19:21(')
insert into testtable values('08:19:21"')
```

Here's my problem, when I sort the values, I get this:

```
select *
from (
    select timeenter
        , ascii(right(timeenter,1)) as ascvalue
        , right(timeenter,1) as symbol
    from testtable 
) x
order by timeenter
```

Result set:

```
timeenter                      ascvalue    symbol
------------------------------ ----------- ------
08:19:21'                      39          '
08:19:21"                      34          "
08:19:21$                      36          $
08:19:21%                      37          %
08:19:21(                      40          (
```

When I order by with this: `order by timeenter collate Latin1_General_BIN` or `order by timeenter collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_BIN`, it sorts correctly:

```
timeenter                      ascvalue    symbol
------------------------------ ----------- ------
08:19:21"                      34          "
08:19:21$                      36          $
08:19:21%                      37          %
08:19:21'                      39          '
08:19:21(                      40          (
```

I looked up `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` collation and CP1 shows that the character set is properly ordered but the sort order is still irregular in my instance for my query.

Is it due to the fact that the apostrophe (') is a delimiter to SQL?

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

The answer i'm looking for is how and why my instance is sorting the way it is based on the current collation. I'm able to make the data sort the way i want via tsql easily. I'm only looking for an explanation in regards to the collation and how it behaves with apostrophes per my example.

Comment: The order of the characters is defined by the collation, *not* the Ascii value, and different collations order the character differently; that is expected behaviour. The *real* question is why are you storing what are obviously times with non-time characters at suffixed onto them, and not a `time` data type.

Comment: @Larnu thank you for your reply. the data and its structure originates from an old custom-developed system that i inherited. it is what it is and there's no changing two decade's worth of data already like this. for whatever reason, the people prior to me chose to suffix characters after a time value as an attempt to create a sort order. i've checked the sort order for the collation and it's still not sorting per the collation.

Comment: If you wanted the ordering specifically based on the ascii value you can always do `order by Ascii(Right(timeenter,1))`

Comment: I would, at least, move the suffix to a different column, @Doua , then you can have strongly typed data. A `time` column with your time, and a `char` column with your suffix.

Comment: @Stu thank you for your reply. i'm very aware that i may change the sort via tsql. i'm looking to know more about my collation and why it does what it does with apostrophes. i could order my query by "symbol" and it would behave the same leading me to hypothesize that my collation is treating apostrophes differently versus a binary-collation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is odd.  `"` < `'` in SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, as you can see

```
select case when '''' collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS < '"' collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS then 1 else 0 end
```

outputs

```
0
```

But if they are unicode characters, the order is reversed:

```
select case when N'''' collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS < N'"' collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS then 1 else 0 end
```

outputs

```
1
```

Comment: THANK YOU for addressing my question at the core of what i was asking for. it took me a couple of takes at your answer to realize that the answer was staring at me right in my face. this is a UNICODE issue. my data type is the problem: NVARCHAR. nvarchar = unicode therefore the sort order is off. if i redo my test table with VARCHAR, the sort works as to what i'm expecting... so now my questions is "does collation ignore data type NVARCHAR?".

Comment: after some researching, NVARCHAR is kinda its own thing with unicode number set. i've gotten the education i was looking for. thank you again!